# When we click checkboxFor then textbox is enable otherwise disable in mvc in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my design code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cirtyfied, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Cirtyfied)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cirtyfied)
        </div>
        </div>            
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CirtyficateName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CirtyficateName)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CirtyficateName)
      </div>
 </div>
```

I don't know how it will perform.

Comment: Use jquery to handle the disabled functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do This Alternate Solution:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
     $(function () {
                            $("[name='Cirtyfied']").click(function () {
                                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                    $("[name='CirtyficateName']").show();
                                    $("[name='cirtyficateName']").hide();
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("[name='CirtyficateName']").hide();
                                    $("[name='cirtyficateName']").show();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CirtyficateName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBox("cirtyficateName", "Enter Cirtyficate Name ",new{disabled="disabled"} )
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CirtyficateName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CirtyficateName)
</script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like this;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[name='Cirtyfied']").change(function(){
        if($("[name='Cirtyfied']").checked){
              $("[name='CirtyficateName']").attr('disabled',true);
              }
        else{
                 $("[name='CirtyficateName']").removeAttr('disabled');
             }
         })
    }
</script>
```

And edit your TextBoxFor like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CirtyficateName, new{disabled="disabled"})
```

Comment: But this code enable once then again i unchecked the checkbox then its not working means textbox not disable when uncheck the checkbox